# Unable to Connect to Azure from Mac

Tags: macos, azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I see Connect-AzureRmAccount command under AzureRM.Profile:

```
Get-Command -Module AzureRM.Profile* 
CommandType Name                    Version
Cmdlet      Connect-AzureRmAccount  0.13.1
```

But when I run it, get following error:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount : The term 'Connect-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzureRmAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-AzureRmAccount:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I searched stackoverflow, checked I have latest Powershell version, have NetCore.Preview installed. Am unable to figure out what is wrong, can anyone please guide?

Answer (score 0):

See these two open issues on the MS PowerShell GitHub

> Powershell Core installation for Mac OSX
>
> https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7178
>
> Documentation: Connect-AzureRmAccount is Wrong?
>
> https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell/issues/552

This means…

> The term 'Connect-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name

… It cannot be found, so acting like it's not auto loading.

So, do an explicit import of the module.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
Import-Module -Name AzureRM -DisableNameChecking -Force
```

Comment: I checked both links, I already have module for NetCore installed and have only dotnet core installed on my pc.

Comment: i am also having same issue.